# Probability Question - team draw from field of 32

Tags: probability, combinatorics

For a sport tournament where two-man teams are drawn from a sample of 32 without replacement, what is the probability of two men being on the same team one year and then two years in a row?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Call the men  A and B. What is the probability that B is chosen to be A's teammate?

If A and B are in the group of $32$ again, what is the probability B is chosen to be A's partner in the second year? Then use independence.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by seeing the bijection. We match up $16$ men to $16$ other men (slots). So there are $16!$ ways to permute the $16$ men on the $16$ slots. However, we must first choose the $16$ men for the slots group, and there are $\binom{32}{16}$ ways to do this. So the probability of two people being paired up is $\dfrac{1}{16! * \binom{32}{16}}$. The teams are independent from year to year, so the odds of them being on the same team next year are the same. So by rule of product, we multiply to get $(\dfrac{1}{16! * \binom{32}{16}})^{2}$ as our answer.